# Report for getting followups outside of start_date parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

This is a function for inquiry report in my software.

```
public function inquiryReports(Request $request)
    {
        $templateData['inquiries'] = [];
        $helpTab = new HelpTabApi();
        $templateData['help_tab_content'] = $helpTab->getHelpTabContent('report_inq_tab');
        $templateData['params'] = $request->except(['_token', '_method', 'submit']);
        $templateData['status'] = $request->status;
        $templateData['start_date'] = $request->start_date;
        $templateData['end_date'] = $request->end_date;
        $templateData['global'] = $request->global = 'true' ? $request->global : 'false';

        if ($request->status && $request->start_date && $request->end_date) {
            $sortBy = $request->sortBy ? $request->sortBy : 'name';
            $sortOrder = $request->order ? $request->order : 'asc';

            $inquiry = ShInquiry::query();

            // When full search is set
            $inquiry->when(!empty($request->full_search), function ($query) {
                $query->where(function ($query) {
                    $query->whereHas('stakeholder', function ($query) {
                        $query->where('stakeholders.full_name', 'like', '%' . request('full_search') . '%')
                            ->orWhereRaw('CONCAT(stakeholders.first_name, " ", stakeholders.last_name) like ?', ['%' . request('full_search') . '%']);
                    });

                });
            });



            $inquiry->when($sortBy === 'name', function ($query) use ($sortOrder) {
                return $query->join('stakeholders as sh', 'sh.id', '=', 'sh_inquiry.sh_id')
                    ->select('sh.id as stakeholderId', 'sh.full_name')
                    ->orderBy(\DB::raw('CONCAT(sh.first_name, " ", sh.last_name)'), $sortOrder);
            });

            $inquiry->when($sortBy === 'method_of_inquiry', function ($query) use ($sortOrder) {
                return $query->join('type_of_contact as toc', 'toc.id', '=', 'sh_inquiry.sh_inquiry_method')
                    ->select('toc.id as tocId', 'toc.type_of_contact_name')
                    ->orderBy('toc.type_of_contact_name', $sortOrder);
            });

            $inquiry->when($sortBy != 'name' && $sortBy != 'method_of_inquiry', function ($query) use ($sortBy, $sortOrder) {
                return $query->orderBy($sortBy, $sortOrder);
            });



            if ($request->status != 3) {
                if (request('status') == 1) {
                    $inquiry->where('sh_inquiry_fu', 1);
                } else {
                    $inquiry->where('sh_inquiry_fu', 0);
                }
            }



            // When StartDate is set
           $inquiry->when(!empty($request->start_date), function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->whereDate('sh_inquiry_date', '>=', Carbon::parse($request->start_date)->toDateString());
});

            // When EndDate is set
            $inquiry->when(!empty($request->start_date), function ($query) {
                $query->whereDate('sh_inquiry_date', '<=', Carbon::parse(request('end_date')));
            });



            if ($request->global == 'true') {
                $templateData['global'] = 'true';
            } else {
                $inquiry->where('sh_inquiry.project_id', session()->get('project_id'));
                $templateData['global'] = 'false';
            }

            if ($request->pdf_export) {
                $templateData['inquiries'] = $inquiry->select('sh_inquiry.*')->get();
                $pdf = PDF::loadView('reports.pdf.inquiry_export', $templateData);
                return $pdf->download('stakeholders.pdf');
            }

            if ($request->excel_export) {
                $inquiries = $inquiry->select('sh_inquiry.*')->get();
                return Excel::download(new InquiryReportsExport($inquiries), 'stakeholders' . Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y') . '.xlsx');
            }

            if ($request->csv_export) {
                $inquiries = $inquiry->select('sh_inquiry.*')->get();
                return Excel::download(new InquiryReportsExport($inquiries), 'stakeholders' . Carbon::now()->format('d-m-Y') . '.csv');
            }

            if ($request->print) {
                $templateData['inquiries'] = $inquiry->select('sh_inquiry.*')->get();
                $loadView = \View::make('reports.inquiry_print', $templateData);
                $content = (string) $loadView;
                $content = $loadView->render();

                return response()->json(['content' => $content]);
            }

            $templateData['inquiries'] = $inquiry->select('sh_inquiry.*')->with('followups')->paginate(10);


            if ($request->ajax()) {
                $pagination = $templateData['inquiries'];
                $pageData = View('reports.inquiry_report_rows', $templateData)->render();
                $paginationData = [
                    'total' => $pagination->total(),
                    'currentPage' => $pagination->currentPage(),
                    'lastPage' => $pagination->lastPage(),
                ];

                return response()->json([
                    'content' => $pageData,
                    'pagination' => $paginationData
                ], 200);
            }
        }
        return View('reports.inquiry_reports', $templateData);
    }
```

This works as expected. It shows all inquires and associated followups within the start_date and end_date parameters. I now need it to show any inquiry and associated followups if a followup happened to an inquiry that is outside the start_date and end_date parameters.

I added the following code:

// get inquiries if a followup happened out the date range

```
$inquiry->whereHas('followups', function ($query) use ($start_date) {
        $query->whereDate('followup_date', '>=', $start_date);
    });
```

Just adding this code resulted in $start_date as being undefined.

So I added

```
$start_date = $request->start_date;
```

I know start_date and end_date are being defined in the request but I could not figure out how to use it from there so I added this line.

Now I get no results. Can someone help point me in the right direction. I'm a larval newbie so take it easy on me.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

> Just adding this code resulted in $start_date as being undefined.

Yes, this is expected - even though you told the query to use `$start_date`, you had not assigned the variable yet.

Your solution to add `$start_date = $request->start_date;` was correct.

The query failure is likely due to a mismatch of date format.  The query expects "Y-m-d".

You can try:

`$start_date = $start_date->toDateString();`

or even

`$start_date = $start_date->format("Y-m-d");`

This assumes the date is readable.  If it is some wacky format and the format returns an error, you can try to parse with Carbon:

`$start_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($start_date)->format("Y-m-d");`

but this shouldn't be necessary - the format from the request item should help you.

Comment: I got it to give me results by using your last suggestion:

 $start_date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->start_date)->format("Y-m-d");

It is still not giving the expected results:

Comment: Here is the query I'm getting from the laravel bar plugin:


select count(*) as aggregate from `sh_inquiry` inner join `stakeholders` as `sh` on `sh`.`id` = `sh_inquiry`.`sh_id` where exists (select * from `followup` where `sh_inquiry`.`id` = `followup`.`followup_inquiry_id` and date(`followup_date`) >= '2023-06-01' and `followup`.`deleted_at` is null) and date(`sh_inquiry_date`) >= '2023-06-01' and date(`sh_inquiry_date`) <= '2023-06-30' and `sh_inquiry`.`project_id` = '17' and `sh_inquiry`.`deleted_at` is null

Comment: I added a followup on 06/20/2023 for a inquiry on 05/01/2023. This should show up but I think it is because the inquiry date is 05/01/2023.

Do you see an problems in the query? Any Ideas?

Comment: No I think this correctly solves your issue.  The query appears to be doing it job.  The carbon parse is doing its job.  If the data is in the right place at the right date, it should correctly provide the info.  I think this solves the date issue.  You may have other items (ids or something in the join) that are making this incorrect, but that is a different question.  You can use tinker to test by making the query simpler - just put in the dates via a simple query and see when it functions based on data in the DB.  But I believe this answers the direct question you had.